# Jquery is not working in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse

I have jquery-1.9.1.jar file in lib folder but when i take source like this

```
<script src="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-1.9.1.jar" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle();
});
</script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
```

the above code it's not working is there any jquery file missing append   to eclipse neon

File Structure:

Comment: can you add your file structure's screen shot

Comment: @selvarajmas, I edited my screenshot

Comment: I don't know how add  jquery file to eclipse can you please tell me which way i add to eclipse i need to do my application in jquery thank you

Comment: Try to include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @selvarajmas, when i click button it didn't do any action it's not working for what i missing in this could you please tell me

Comment: Hi, when i interact with Jquery can i add or change  any settings into my eclipse neon IDE

Comment: Take the look at http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/2/JSP-Hello-World-Program-using-Eclipse-IDE-and-Tomcat-web-server

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>  
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
             $("p").toggle();
        });
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little explanation as to how and why your answer could work would be nice. Now it's just a piece of code.

Comment: because earlier code consists of white space in button id , para tag too. So,we don't need to  include space before and after id at the time of function calling using id and we must use document ready function , the script mentioned in above code. Hope it will help you.Thanks

Comment: now @Robert E you can refer above code which I implemented recently.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. You can use "googleapis" or "CDN" to import jquery.

googleapis:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle();
});
</script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
```

CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle();
});
</script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
```